# Set up SQL Server on home network

Tags: sql-server, webserver

I am new to SQL Server and server setup in general.

I just set up a home network file share with an old Lenovo running XP as file server over WAN, and installed SQL Server Express 2008 on the machine.

So now I am a bit stuck on what steps I need to take now to access data on that SQL Server instance. I tried to establish an ODBC connection through a MS Access database on a client computer, but the instance is unavailable in the dropdown list and typing in the address via Computer\SQLInstance syntax yields an unavailable error.

Please keep in mind this is the first time I have tried to set up a home server as well, so I'm not sure if I have to modify the type of server I have set up.

Here is why I am doing this.

I want to set up the db and start learning SQL Server (used by my company) and web development. So I was thinking create a home db, and start building pages around it. I would want access to pages from any device that is on my home network, and the ability to pipe in an ODBC connection directly to the DB.

To do this, do I have to setup a web server? If not, can you provide advice or links to guides that can help me sort this out? I have looked around for the last day and have tried many solutions but none of them have resolved my issue.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: In your description, you used `WAN` to describe what sounds like a `LAN`.  Are you trying to access it from outside your home as well as all devices within your home?  To make it work on your home network, you need to make sure the XP box where SQL Server is installed allows the SQL Server instance to broadcast itself on port 1434, and accept incoming connections on port 1433.  You likely need to configure the firewall on your XP server.  Are you able to access the server from the server itself (e.g., localhost access)?

Comment: What protocols have you enabled for the SQL Server instance (e.g., named pipes, tcp/ip, etc.)?  What protocol is the ODBC connection using?

Comment: Good point.  Right now just accessing from within my home. I had modified firewall for TCP 1433, and after reading your post added TCP 1434.  Still unable to ping the Server with telnet.  The enabled protocols are Shared Memory, TCP/IP, and Named Pipes.  FWIW this is the result of a query to discover my Servers connection properties.  <net_transport>Shared memory  <protocol_type>TSQL <auth_scheme>NTLM <local_net_address>NULL <local_tcp_port>NULL <client_net_address>local machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's many possible issues here, including all or one of the below

1. **Test Open Port** The network on your LAN, can you ping SQL Server remotely on the default port 1433 on the specific IP Address (you can use PuTTY or Telnet to check this)
2. **SQL Configuration Manager** Check SQL Configuration Manager and see if the Network Protocol for SQL is enabled for TCP/IP, Named Pipes or Shared Memory
3. **Firewall and Default Port** Check the Windows Firewall make sure its allowing 1433.  Since you are testing, best thing to do is to disable the Firewall in Windows Services to confirm whether its a firewall issue or not.
4. **SQL Server Browser** SQL Server Instances (instances have the form SERVER\SQLEXPRESS or SERVERNAME\SQL1 for example).  Check in services and makes sure the "SQL Server Browser" is running.  Also, you must allow a Firewall rule for port 1434, which is the default port of the "SQL Server Browser".  This is necessary because the SQL Server maps and forwards the traffic based on the Instance Name, so this is the service that resolves the instance name.
5. **SQL Server Instance Port Varies** SQL Server Instances does not necessarily run on port 1433, in this case you will have to have the SQL Browser Running which maps the name to the port and directs traffic to the correct instance.  In your firewall, instead of allowing port 1433, you will have to allow sqlservr.exe Executeable Program.  The port also can be determined by looking at the SQL Server log File in the MSSQL\LOG folder in Program Files.  There will be an entry for "Server is listening on port ..."

My recommendation for you is to install SQL Server Express Management Studio (SSMS) which is the GUI interface to manage the SQL Server Express instance.  The link is below for both SQL Express and SQL Management Studio.  And see if you can connect to the servers that way first.  Another suggestion is for you to install both on a Local Computer and simply familarize yourself with SQL Server first before exposing it on the Network.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062

Comment: Thank you for your response.  When attempting 1), I get an error {Could not open connection to the host, on port 1433: Connect Failed}.  I get the same result pinging on server computer itself or from remote laptop. Does this mean server is not broadcasting? Here is the telnet command I used to ping: telnet <COMPUTERNAME>\<SERVERINSTANCE> 1344 . Regarding step 2), I have verified that all 3 are enabled for Native Client and Network Configuration.  Also using Management Studio, but was testing remote access with MS-Access.

Comment: If you go to the Services (go to DOS and type services.msc at the comamnd line) Do you see MSSQL or SQL Server Service running and started?  That is the first thing to check.  To make sure the Service itself is running.  While you have Servies open, stop the Windows Firewall so that you can test a Remote Connection without the Firewall interfering.  This will allow you to narrow down your issue.  If its the Firewall, simply allow the port 1433 in Windows Firewall. It does not need to broadcast for you to connect.  First test all the ports locally, then remotely from another computer.

Comment: I was able to confirm SQL Server is started in services.msc.  I also turned off the firewall completely.  The problem persisted, so I dug around firewall and notice a bunch of network connection settings were disabled under the advanced tab.  I enabled most of them.  No change. Found a windows troubleshooting ref and looked in the log file viewer for "server is listening on" and according to MS it should be 1433.  However, it shows my instance is listening on 1186.  Tried..  telnet MyComputer\SQLEXPRESS 1186 but still no connection can be made.  Is this port difference possibly an issue?

Comment: If you did a default install your instance will be listening on 1433.  Unless you explicitly changed your port in SQL Server Configuration Manager its unlikely your SQL Server is running on 1186.  If you do "C:\telnet localhost 1433" and it does not work respond (ie does not connect to anything), then its likely you are not using TCP/IP but rather just Named Pipes.  You should check your Network Configuration of SQL Server in SQL Server Configuration Manager and look at Protocols for MSSQLSERVER\SQLEXPRESS under SQL Server Network Configuration

Comment: Make sure you are checking both the Client Network Config and the Server Network Config.

Comment: Your comment about named pipes got me thinking... All three (Shared Memory, Named Pipes, and TCP/IP) were enabled and TCP\IP had last priority.  I disabled the other two, and viola the Server is now broadcasting to my other computer.  Now just have to figure out how to access to the darn thing!

Answer (score 1):

As CodeCowboyOrg said there are a few possible reasons for this.  A couple other things to check (and honestly I'd check these first) are:

1) Make sure the SQL Server is running.  Find the SQL Server Surface Area Configuration app and make sure SQL Server is started.
2) Hopefully you have SQL Server Management Studio, it should have installed with the database itself... so go into it, and make sure you can connect to the database server while you're on the same computer.
     2a) Once connected, right click the server in Object Explorer and select properties.  The go to connections and make sure that Allow Remote Connections to this server is checked
3) Make sure Windows Firewall (or any other firewall) is not blocking the port

As a side note, you'll probably also want to click security while you're in the properties window, and allow SQL Authentication mode so that you can create standard SQL accounts for authentication to the server.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  From management studio I can connect, add tables and databases to the server.  I have also verified that Allow Remote Connections is checked.  However, I have yet to successfully ping the server outside the SQL Server application.

Comment: Edited it in, but make sure you check windows firewall as it could be blocking the port for SQL.

Comment: Turned off firewall completely but to no avail.  Dug around and discovered my instance is listening on port 1186 as opposed to 1433.  Tried to add an exception on this port and ping with telnet, but still no connection could be made.

Comment: Have you verified remote connections are allowed by SQL server?

Comment: Yes I verified this as well.